# Query oddly not using index

Tags: mysql

I have a table with an index on the field `platform_id`. When I do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY platform_id
```

It takes about 5s to do, and when I run the `EXPLAIN` query, it shows that it is NOT using the `platform_id` index. However, when I run:

```
SELECT * FROM table force index (platform_id) ORDER BY platform_id
```

It runs instantaneously and uses the index. Why does my index seem to be 'broken' if not explicitly telling mysql to use it? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Can you add show create table output to your post?

Comment: Does it still do it when you specify columns instead of `*`?

Comment: Post the `CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN` so we can see them.